# translate angular variables in django template

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-templates

In my django project I can easily translate any string by the tag below:

```
{% trans "any string" %}
```

but there is a drop-down list in a page. I used angularjs to get the drop-down values as like below:

```
<select class="form-control btn-bar-select"
                ng-model="selectedDivision" ng-change="changeDivision()"
                ng-options="division as division.name for division in divisions">
            <option value="">{% trans "Select Division" %}</option>
        </select>
```

I want to translate the drop-down list. Here **division.name** is responsible for the drop-down list values.

Can I bring this under **trans tag** of django or any other way?

Comment: You template is server side built but angular is on different origin you cannot use django template language there I think you are looking for `ng-for`

Comment: You won't be able to use trans within your js code, have you looked https://angular.io/guide/i18n ?

Comment: There are many ways of translating strings in JS. Not very acquainted to Angular, but in Vue JS I use `gettext()`.